# Cannot properly centre nav bar (uses col-md-3) bootstrap css and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, centering

so basically I've got this code: HTML and CSS below, using bootstrap as well, and for some reason, it's not centred. It used to be, but at some point it wasn't anymore, now it pulls to the left. See image below. Any ideas?

```
<div class="row" id="nav-bar">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ul>
            <li class="col-md-3 nav-btn" id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-3 nav-btn" id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-3 nav-btn dropdown-toggle" id="games">
                <a href="#">Games & Apps &#9660;</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="games2">Games & Apps &#9660;</a></li>
                        <li id="first"><a href="#">Space Rodeo</a></li>
                        <li id="spaced"><a href="#">Boodya's Carpet Ride</a></li>
                        <li id="spaced"><a href="#">Ultimate Points Counter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3 nav-btn" id="blog"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>                              
</div>

#nav-bar {
margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;  
height: 60px;
}

#nav-bar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;   
}

.col-md-3 a {
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #B6B6B6;
}

#nav-bar a:hover {
    color: #428bca;
}

.col-md-3 {
    display: inline;   
}

.col-md-9 {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -48px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 210px;
    width: 275px;
}

.dropdown ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.dropdown li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 310px;
}

#games2 {
    color: #428bca;
}

#spaced {
    margin-top: 10px;   
}

#first {
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Showing result of code, the navbar is off centre

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smtTP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list items are `display: inline` which means they'll follow the alignment rules of text. Since you set no `text-align`, it defaults to the left. You can fix that by adding `text-align: center` to your `ul` so the contents will be centered.

Now the insides of the dropdown will also inherit that, you can reset that by setting `text-align: left` back on the dropdown `ul` again.

Also reset the left padding that `ul` has by default.

```
#nav-bar ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav-bar .dropdown  ul {
     text-align: left;   
}
```

Works in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v97jru4g/)